# Using enable_if to hide member function according to template type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

I want my class template to provide an extra function member if the template parameter matches a specific type. I am trying to use `std::enable_if` to get a SFINAE implementation, but I am struggling to find the correct syntax for this. I've tried several solutions for similar questions, but for some reason none of them compile.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template < typename T >
class myClass {
 public:
    using value_type = T;
    using other_type = int;

    myClass() = default;
    virtual ~myClass() = default;

    // 'default' member
    void function(const value_type& val) {};

    // overload #1
    // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
    template < typename = typename std::enable_if< !std::is_convertible< other_type, value_type >::value >::type >
    void function(const other_type& val) {};

    // overload #2
    // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
    template < std::enable_if_t< !std::is_convertible< other_type, value_type >::value >* = nullptr >
    void function(const other_type& val) {};
};



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    myClass< std::string > foo;  // OK
    myClass< float > bar;            // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’

    return 0;
}
```

I want `function` to be available for all types, but its overload to *only* be available when `other_type` is not implicitly convertible to `value_type`. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Do you have access to C++20? `requires(!std::is_convertible<other_type, value_type >::value)` would solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the `function` member function template overloads, the SFINAE constructs (`std::enable_if_t`) contains no *dependent type*, meaning there's no substitutation context, and the failures in the template-head's of the overloads are not substitutation failures, they're hard errors. Recall:

- SFINAE - *Substitutation* Failure Is Not An Error

You typically solve this by adding a dummy template parameter whose default-template-argument is that of the enclosing class template's template parameter which you originally used directly (`T`; your value type):

```
template <typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<
                              !std::is_convertible<other_type, U>::value>::type>
void function(const other_type &val){};

template <
    typename U = T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<other_type, U>::value> * = nullptr>
void function(const other_type &val){};
```

The `std::enable_if_t` SFINAE constructs are now dependent in the context of each member function template overload.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the correct syntax to employ `std::enable_if` for this particular purpose (I'm assuming it is possible?)

Comment: @joaocandre See the updated answer (I updated it at the same time as you asked you question :) ).

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For SFINAE to apply, you need the thing you are trying to use SFINAE on to have it's own template argument, and you need to use that template argument in the condition. In this case, you could fix it by adding a template argument `typename V = value_type` to the template arguments and using `V` instead of `value_type`. Now the condition would depend on `V` which is a template argument of the member function :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template < typename T >
class myClass {
 public:
    using value_type = T;
    using other_type = int;

    myClass() = default;
    virtual ~myClass() = default;

    // 'default' member
    void function(const value_type& val) {};

    // overload #1
    // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
    template < typename V = value_type, typename = typename std::enable_if< !std::is_convertible< other_type, V >::value >::type >
    //   added ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               changed value_type to V ^
    void function(const other_type& val) {};

    // overload #2
    // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
    template < typename V = value_type, std::enable_if_t< !std::is_convertible< other_type, V >::value >* = nullptr >
    //   added ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             changed value_type to V ^
    void function(const other_type& val) {};
};



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    myClass< std::string > foo;  // OK
    myClass< float > bar;        // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the introduction of concepts in C++20, most of SFINAE machinaries
can be simplified or at least expressed less verbosely.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template < class Type >
class myClass {
 public:
    myClass() = default;

    void function(Type const& val) {
        std::cout << "Default: " << val << "\n";
    }

    template < class Other >
        requires (not std::convertible_to<Other, Type>)  // <- Constrain
    void function(Other const& val) {
        std::cout << "Overload: " << val << "\n";
    }
};



int main()
{
    myClass< std::string > foo;
    foo.function("OK");          // Default
    foo.function(42);            // Overload

    myClass< float > bar;
    bar.function(42);            // Default
    bar.function("OK");          // Overload
    bar.function(3.14);          // Default
}
```

Comment: For those of you, like me, who want to allow/disallow a function which doesn't take an Other as an argument, you can still use the tric above, by defining the template with a default template argument:
```
template<typename U = Type> requires (some condtion)
void function(); // Only instantiated if some condtion is true
```